# is there a way to declare " IWebelement element " variable globally like IWebdriver driver in c#

Tags: c#, automation, nunit

have seen that for IWebDriver driver it can be declared globally ..
and therefore it can be used anywhere down the program..for eg.

namespace TestProject1.BaseClass

{

```
public class BaseTest

{

   

    public IWebDriver driver;

    [OneTimeSetUp]

    public void Test1()

    {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]

    public void Test2()

    {

        driver.Quit();

    }

}
```

}

but I'm not able to declare
"IWebElement ele" the same way..that is as a global variable...

i see im having an error when i do that

" Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable"

how can i rectify this?

Comment: Declare it nullably (i.e. `IWebElement? ele`), or initialize it in the constructor, or turn off nullable reference type support. (I'm surprised you're not seeing the same behavior in your current code with the `driver` field, mind you...)